# What now... Godaddy host not support charting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, godaddy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I was going to use the asp.net charting with Visual Studios 2008 but GoDaddy hosting does not support the charting cause they won't install the component.

So what are my options for charting/graphs for data?  Looking for free if possible.

Is Telerix the best?

Comment: Find a better host.

Comment: just place the correct dll inside your bin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft ASP.Net Charting, then you don't need to install that components. Only that DLL files must exist in your *bin* directory.

I worked on a project, where I used ASP.net charting. Mine was shared hosting and I hope yours  is also on a shared host. I just copied the required DLL into the *bin* directory and it started working.

Otherwise you can do one thing: You can change the build property of the reference as copy to local before publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Google has some basic charting, and requires no installation at your host. Unless they have enhanced them a lot lately, they are basic charts in lots of styles. The price is right, anyway.

https://developers.google.com/chart/